# How to list installed man pages and search in many mans?

Tags: linux, man

I am frustrated that to use `man` I need to know the exact name of the topic, and usually I need to search on Internet before I can open the man page. How to list installed man pages? How to search for a word inside all installed mans or search for many mans and then search inside them?

So far I can only do this:

```
man ls | col -b | grep -i color
```

Comment: `man apropos`, `apropos string`

Comment: You can try **man -k .**  where the dot will mean any pattern. 
if you want to search for anything more specific you can specify it as **man -k iscsiadm** 
or any other pattern in place of iscsiadm.

Comment: You should have looked at the manual page for `man` first ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn to the man page of "man" itself, and search "search", and you will find:

man -k xxx

which searchs the short descriptions and manual page names, equivalent to apropos -r xxx.

man -K xxx

which searchs for text in all manual pages.

man -S, man -I, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will list all the installed man pages in linux.

**man -k .**